# JSON,array and slash escaping

Tags: php

How to escape string in JSON? Seems that JSON will escape back slashes.
How do I `json_encode(array('name'=>'what\'s the name'))`?

Comment: Your code should work fine: http://codepad.org/qFXbbb1C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well firstly, you can start by doing this:

```
json_encode(array("name" => "what's the name"));
```

PHP, Python, Javascript, etc. all allow the use of both single- and double-quotes for just such an occasion. Use them!

Secondly, the way you want to do this is probably not just `'`, but `\'`, which means you *actually* need `\\\'`. Try this:

```
json_encode(array('name'=>'what\\\'s the name'));
```

Thirdly, since you're getting the information from `$_POST`, the string is already known-good. Simply:

```
array_push($info, array('name'=>$_POST['name']));
json_encode($info);
```

Comment: I believe that would still break in PHP. If the backslash needs to be in the string when it's passed to json_encode, three backslashes are actually needed. `json_encode(array('name'=>'what\\\'s the name'));`

Comment: Well,actually I use array_push() to generate the array:array_push($info,array('name'=>addslahses($_POST['name']))).I can't decide whether to use double-quotes or single-quotes. How do I do it correctly?

Comment: I think you might want to use array_merge() instead. array_push() will add your new array as an element to $info. array_merge() will add each element in the new array to $info separately. So it would be: `$info = array_merge($info, array(...));`

Comment: But regardless, I'm not sure I understand the issue with the quotes. If you're getting the strings from the $_POST variable, why do you need to worry about quotes?

Comment: Why don't i worry about quotes because I get string from $_POST? Will strings come from $_POST striped automatically?I'm using json to store the data come from users.If the users' data contains ' when i get data using $info=json_decode($info);echo $info->name i'll get an error.

Comment: @LotusH: `array_push($info, array('name'=>$_POST['name']))` should work just fine.  You don't need to `addslashes`, that's the problem here.

Comment: @Rocket But actually it doesn't work fine.I got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in var\webroot\includes\CMS\info.php on line 1,and Line 1 is:<?php $info='[{"id":"","name":"test's test","gender":"","intro":""}...

Comment: @LotusH: `"test's test"` should be `"test\'s test"`.  But that's a parse error, that's different than what you're asking.

Comment: If these informations are useful: This is a simple CMS application. The work flow is, first get data from user and make it an array then json_encode it and using fwrite to store it in a PHP file,as shown in the above comment. Include this file and json_decode it when I need these data

Comment: @LotusH, Rocket's last comment is the key here. You have a string that contains your JSON string and is surrounded by single quotes, and in your JSON string, you use single quotes. PHP thinks your string (the JSON string) is ending earlier than it is. As Rocket said, you need to escape any single quotes in your JSON string since you surrounded the whole thing in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for you all. Solved by escape the whole json string.

Comment: @Compeek By the way, I should use addcslashes(json_encode($info),'\'') but not addslashes(json_encode($info)), since addslashes will also add slashes to backslashes in json strings which are used by json to represent multibyte characters like chinese characters(e.g. \u6d4b for '测').